# Is it possible to change storage of an existing EC2 instance on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, storage

I am working with a p2.xlarge instance on AWS, and it has 120 GiB storage. I am in need of more storage as it is running out of memory. I am looking into options of changing the storage, but I can't find a way to alter it. Does anyone know if this is possible at all? Or alternatively, should I launch a new instance and move all my work to the new instance? Tips on how to do this most efficiently are much appreciated.

Comment: Is it happening because of the Service quota limit or else? If you want to expand the volume find your attached volume from EC2 console and modify the volume and If you want to change the root volume. **1** Create volume in EC2 console with same snapshot ID of attached volume. **2** Attache newly created volume with EC2 instance. **3** make this newly attached volume as root volume. **4** detach Old volume from Instance. **If you want to change your volume so, be careful you will lose your old data**

Comment: Can you clarify the issue? You can't just [extend](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ebs-volume-increase-os/) it as you would normally do?

Comment: i have tried this approach and it worked
1) stop your instance ( don't terminate)
2) go to volumes, find the volume attached to your ec2 instance using its instance id 
3) select it and click on modify and enter your desired size.
to confirm ssh into your instance use df -h

Comment: the about approach will increase the size of root partition.

Comment: I agree with @Marcin. Simply follow the instructions to [extend](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ebs-volume-increase-os/) the EBS Volume and inform the operating system.

Comment: Glad it worked. If you don't mind I will provide an answer for future reference.

Comment: Well, regarding to @JatinMehrotra's comment it is not necessary to stop your instance. Follow this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html#extend-file-system) for that use case, when you can't stop your instance... and if you can't extend volume because of **no space left on device** follow [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ebs-volume-size-increase/) link. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

You can extend EBS volume as shown in the AWS documentation:

- [Extending a Linux file system after resizing a volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html)  and
- [How do I extend my Linux file system after increasing my EBS volume on my EC2 instance?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/extend-linux-file-system/)